# Problem with configuring and starting WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configuration

I have a problem with configuration and starting WCF service.
In my application there is a method that starts service. Something like this

```
void Start(string protocol, string address, string port)
{
    host = new ServiceHost(_myService,
        new Uri(String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}/Sample", protocol, address, port)));
    //...Some configuration (bindings, behaviors, etc.)
    host.Open();
}
```

Let my computer has an IP 192.168.0.1. When I pass 'address' parameter with a value '192.168.0.2' an error occurred

```
"A TCP error (10049: The requested address is not valid in its context.)
 occurred while listening on IP Endpoint=192.168.0.2:1234"
```

That's right because it's not my IP. But after that if I pass correct value (my real IP) I get the same error about IP 192.168.0.2! So I can't reconfigure and restart server without restarting application.

Why does it happen? How can I avoid such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see from your question how you are adding the correct endpoint, but I suspect you are attempting to modify the endpoint address. With WCF services, you cannot make changes to the endpoint address after calling

```
host.Open();
```

because at this point the service is (if you have no errors) up and accepting requests from clients at the specified address and port number.

You need to create a new ServiceHost object with the correct endpoint address (and dispose of the old one) if you wish to host the service at a new address.

EDIT:

After playing around with the example solution you have posted, I have found a solution to the issue. I think something is going wrong because you are using the same port number for both tries (in the example solution I downloaded you don't specify this, so the port defaulted to 808). The error you are experiencing vanishes if you change your code as follows to specify a different port number in the base address for the 2nd try:

```
 try
        {
            var host2 = CreateServiceHost("localhost:5432", serviceImpl);

            Console.WriteLine("#2, config: " + host2.BaseAddresses.First().ToString());

            host2.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

There seems to be something buggy underneath WCF itself, probably on a socket level, where the port is somehow still unavailable after the first error with the incorrect IP.

I did a quick google and [found this article](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/734497-closing-c-socket-does-not-release-port) where someone experienced a delay in reusing a port after closing a socket. If you always need to use the same port number, perhaps you could wait a certain amount of time for the port to become free again before trying to create the service host again.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I have a trouble when calling method 'Start' once more after startup failure on wrong IP. The matter is that I create every time a new instance of ServiceHost as you can see. If previous attempt to start service failed, the new one using new instance and new configuration will fail too and error will be the same as in previous attempt (including previous IP, even I supply new correct IP)

Comment: Could it be pulling the previous IP address from your app.config file? When you create a service host from an application it will automatically pick up any endpoints you have configured in the app.config file for the host application.

Comment: No it can't be... There is no service configuration data in app.config at all.
If I restart service using real IPs (e.g. 127.0.0.1, then 192.168.0.1, then my Internet IP) all is OK. But restarting after attempt with an incorrect IP always fails

Comment: Interesting. Does this happen even if you wrap the code for host.open() in a try-catch, and close / dispose the service upon catching the IP address error? Can you post the code you are using so I can give it a try myself? :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have created a test project for that issue. http://www.filefactory.com/file/cc893b3/n/ServiceConfigTest.zip

Comment: Great, I will take a look at it tonight and get back to you :)

Comment: Good catch. Looks like WCF tries use same socket objects and\or caches connection address enywhere. After few hours of googling i found similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112457/wcf-sending-the-same-exception-even-if-the-service-endpoint-address-is-valid . Unfortunately it's also unresolved. Time interval between calls not important. I will fix this issue in my project by restricting user input to only valid adresses. But i don't know how to fix that at all (let's assume situation when desired port already taken, so client stop's it's listener and retry to start our service).

Comment: You could test the address and port number entered by the user before creating the service host? Perhaps using some old school code to just create your own socket using the details that you want to test, and then you have full control to close and dispose the socket. If you don't get any errors then you know the address is safe to use to create a ServiceHost object :)

Comment: @Ivan If this was the answer to your question, can you mark it as the accepted answer with the green tick at the side? That way we both get reputation points. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like WCF caches a socket object in class ExclusiveTCPTransportManager.

It's seems to be good solution for me:

```
public static class WCFBugWorkaround
{
    public static bool IsConnectionPossible(this ServiceHost host)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var baseAddress in host.BaseAddresses)
            {
                IPAddress[] ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(baseAddress.DnsSafeHost);
                IPAddress ipAddr = ipAddresses.Where(e => e.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).FirstOrDefault();

                if (ipAddr == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                using (Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
                {
                    System.Net.IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, baseAddress.Port);
                    s.Bind(localEP);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

ServiceHost host = ...;

...

if (host.IsConnectionPossible())
{
    host.Open();
}
```

Thank's to Francheska for showing me the right direction :)